# Matching regular expressions in Android

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to extract specific information from a string like this:

```
String content = "ObjectValue(Name1) ObjectValue(Name2) ObjectValue(Name3)";
```

I want to use regular expressions in order to extract only:

```
Name1 Name2 Name3
```

But I can't succeed. Here's my code:

```
private static final String OBJECT_VALUE = "ObjectValue";
String content = "ObjectValue(Name1) ObjectValue(Name2) ObjectValue(Name3)";
String patternString = OBJECT_VALUE+"\\((.+)\\)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
    
if(matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            Log.d("Found items", matcher.group(i));
        }
        
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
Found items: ObjectValue(Name1) ObjectValue(Name2) ObjectValue(Name3)
```

So, first of all, I want to extract only the names, and I clearly missing something in the regex. Secondly, I want distinct elements of the group, while in the output, the group consist of a single element, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a non-greedy regex *and* use `while` to grab only Group 1 value:

```
String content = "ObjectValue(Name1) ObjectValue(Name2) ObjectValue(Name3)";
String patternString = OBJECT_VALUE+"\\(([^()]+)\\)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
while(matcher.find()) {
    Log.d("Found item:", matcher.group(1));
}
```

See [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/gWTWJl)

**Patter details**:

- `\\(` - a literal `(`
- `([^()]+)`  - Group 1 matching 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` (the one that is accessed with `matcher.group(1)`)
- `\\)` - a literal `)`

Note that `if` turned into `while`, and there is no need to loop over `matcher.groupCount()` since we know that the required value is in Group 1.

Comment: What can I say? Simply GREAT! Thanks Wiktor.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Wiktor's answer, there are two problems here.

The first is that, for the input string `"ObjectValue(Name1) ObjectValue(Name2) ObjectValue(Name3)"` and the pattern `ObjectValue\((.+)\)`, the `.+` can match `"Name1) ObjectValue(Name2) ObjectValue(Name3"`.

The second is that `matcher.group(0)` behaves a little strangely. From the documentation:

> Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group()